# Как на уровне SQL базы данных реализовать условие чтобы у товары в зависимости от вида их категории имели разные свойства?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Планируется создать интернет-магазин в нем будет несколько категорий товаров, при этом товары разных категорий будут очень сильно отличаться друг от друга. Например, категория 1 -телефоны/мобильные устройства, категория 2 - мебель для офисов.

Так как товары разных категорий практически не имеют общих свойств в зависимости от вида категории у товаров будут разные свойства. Например у товара планшет Apple iPad (2018) 32Gb (категория мобильные устройства) будут такие свойства: встроенная память, операционная система, размер экрана и тд. У товара Стол компьютерный Mon_СК 01 Бук будут такие свойства: материал мебели, габариты, схема сборки.

Вопрос как можно на уровне SQL Базы Данных реализовать бизнес логику с условием, чтобы у товаров в зависимости от вида их категории имели разные свойства?

На уровне логики интернет-магазина планируются следующие сущности: город, категория товаров, товар со свойствами.

Comment: Вариантов много, но всё зависит от желаемого результата, выбора SQL сервера

Answer (score 0):

Либо [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), либо поля типа JSON.

Comment: Бывают случаи когда категорий не много, и под каждую категорию лучше завести отдельную таблицу "свойств" товара ибо JSon - лишает нас многих плюсов при выборке из BD, а EAV - неплохой такой оверхэд, поэтому таки стоит уточнить у автора что именно он собирается делать с этими полями(выборка по ним - ставит крест на JSon во многих SQL серверах).